# How can I check for an already logged-in user on initial render using Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm seeing an issue where Firestore's `auth.currentUser` is always null on my app's initial render. Here's a simplified version of my component:

```
import ...

const [isInitialRender, setIsInitialRender] = useState(true);

const firebaseConfig = {...}
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 

// Auth
export const auth = getAuth();
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099"); // Maybe part of the problem?

// DB
export const db = getFirestore();
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);   

useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitialRender) {
      setIsInitialRender(() => false);

      //Attempt to check existing authentication
      if (auth.currentUser) console.log("Logged in"); // Never logs
      
      return;
    }
    
    if (auth.currentUser) console.log("Logged in"); // Works fine
}
```

I stole my login function from the docs. It looks something like this:

```
const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {})
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log("Google login encountered error:");
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });
};
```

This seems to work just fine - I can log in and console log user info, as well as log out and confirm `auth.currentUser` is null. It just seems like the code in `useEffect()` runs before `currentUser` is populated.

Any thoughts on how to get around this? Or maybe a better way to check for authentication on page load?

Comment: Use `onAuthStateChanges()` check are user exists, then assign him to something.

Comment: Got it, I see that now in the docs as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this as community wiki.As mentioned above in comments by Mises

The onAuthStateChanged() observer is triggered on sign-in or sign-out.[Set an authentication state observer and get user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data)

> For each of your app's pages that need information about the signed-in
> user, attach an observer to the global authentication object. This
> observer gets called whenever the user's sign-in state changes.
>
> Attach the observer using the onAuthStateChanged method. When a user
> successfully signs in, you can get information about the user in the
> observer.
>
> ```
> import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
>
> const auth = getAuth();
> onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
>     // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
>     const uid = user.uid;
>     // ...
>   } else {
>     // User is signed out
>     // ...
>   }
> });
> ```